# Interpretation of synchroton radiation formula

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, classical-electrodynamics, synchrotron-radiation

I'm asked to interpret the formula of the power of synchrotron radiation per solid angle for a single point charge in an uniform circular motion:

$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial \Omega}=\frac{q^2 a^2}{16\pi^2\varepsilon_0 c^3}\frac{1}{(1-\beta \cos(\theta))^3}(1-\frac{(1-\beta^2)\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\phi)}{(1-\beta \cos(\theta))^2})
$$
where $\theta,\phi$ are the polar and azimuth angles (measured from the charge), $\beta$ is the quotient of the carges speed by the speed of light, $a$ is the charge's acceleration and $q$ its charge.

I've tried ploting it as a function of  $\theta,\phi$, but I seem to lack the necessary spatial intuition to make much sense of it.

Any remarks on the geometry the radiated energy and its physical meaning would be of great interest to me.

Comment: Can you post a picture that you've got for the angles? I think, another interesting thing to look at is how total power is distributed with respect to the particle's velocities. Otherwise, I am sure, if you will do a smart google search, you will find a lot of sources where ppl do careful analyses of similar equations... as a reference and example...